# PHP HttpErrorResponse

Tags: php, angular, rxjs, xmlhttprequest

I am running withcredentials: true on all of my calls for my php scripts so that I can verify that a user is the correct user with my sessions. This works on all my scripts so far that are retrieving data and are creating posts. My issues is with my delete.php script for example. I obviously don't want every user to be able to delete a single post, so I am checking on the back end that the user is correct through a series of if statements like usual. Through that it is checking if the session account id is the correct account id, but with a different URL being called then normal I am receiving an error. I don't really know the best way to solve this?

The code that I am using to call this:

```
delete(id: number){
  return this.httpClient.delete<Policy>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/delete.php/?id=${id}`, {withCredentials:true});
}
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/delete.php/?id=150'
```

All of this makes sense. I am just wondering maybe what my headers in my php script will need to say to allow from variable urls the credentials? Thanks!

Comment: use cors header in php like `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");` . Use your front end url in place of "http://localhost:4200"

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @MohammedAzar, thanks. I did that a few minutes ago and that worked. I am now only receiving a single error: `ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/create.php"`

Comment: @MohammedAzar I have this as my headers currently: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');`

Comment: can you show me the php code?